# How to size input input in div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, leaflet

I added inputs into the popup and made them adjustable in size. But popup and input do not grow and shrink at the same rate, how can I fix it?

[image]

```
geojsonLayer3.on('click', function (event) {
 var div = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'leaflet-styleeditor-input');
 var popup = L.popup({ permanent: true, autoClose: false, closeOnClick: false })
     .setLatLng(event.latlng)
     .setContent(div)
     .openOn(map);
     $('#txtFindProject').on('keyup', function () {
var d = $(this).val();
     $(".popupinput").val(d);
     })
     function resizeInput() {
     $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
      }
     $('.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper')
     .keyup(resizeInput)                           
     .each(resizeInput);
     $(".leaflet-popup-content-wrapper").resizable();
```

Comment: A snippet reproducing your problem would be perfect.

Comment: Try to set the size of the `<input />` box to 100%.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup-update